# How to get outputstream from an S3Object?

Tags: java, image-processing, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, apache-commons-imaging

My goal is to fetch an object (image) from S3, change the metadata of the file, and replace it with new file that has changed metadata.

For changing the metadata I am using [commons imaging library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/apidocs/). I have coded the sample below that works as expected but does not deal with S3.

```
File newFile = new File("newImage2.jpg");
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile))
InputStream isNew = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newFile))
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("newImage.jpg")))
try {
            String xmpXml = "<x:xmpmeta>" +
            "\n<Lifeshare>" +
            "\n\t<Date>"+"some date"+"</Date>" +
            "\n\t<Latitude>"+"somelat"+"</Latitude>" +
            "\n\t<Longitude>"+"somelong"+"</Longitude>" +
            "\n\t<Altitude>"+"somealt"+"</Altitude>" +
            "\n\t<Z>"+"someZ"+"</Z>" +
            "\n\t<X>"+"someX"+"</X>" +
            "\n\t<Y>"+"Some y"+"</Y>" +
            "\n</Lifeshare>" +
            "\n</x:xmpmeta>";
            JpegXmpRewriter rewriter = new JpegXmpRewriter();
            rewriter.updateXmpXml(is,os, xmpXml);
            String newXmpXml = Imaging.getXmpXml(isNew, "newImage2.jpg");
            println newXmpXml
        }
finally {
   is.close()
   os.close()
}
```

The above works since I can run `exiftool` on the `newimage2.jpg` and view the set metadata properties:

```
$ exiftool newImage2.jpg | grep "Lifeshare"
Lifeshare Date                  : some date
Lifeshare Latitude              : somelat
Lifeshare Longitude             : somelong
Lifeshare Altitude              : somealt
Lifeshare Z                     : someZ
Lifeshare X                     : someX
Lifeshare Y                     : Some y
```

**Question**

How can I do the same using an object on S3 using AWS S3 SDK? The `updateXmpXml` method above requires `OutputStream` as a second parameter. However, I don't see any outputstream class in the AWS sdk http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/allclasses-noframe.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

using apache [ioutils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream))

```
OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());        
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(
                      new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
    InputStream in= object.getObjectContent();
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);

    in.close();
    out.close();
```

Comment: What should go in `OutputStream os = ...`? I don't want to save the file to a local file system. I just want to work with streams.

Comment: you really dont have to write to temporary file